# ng-click in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot figure out why my ng-click inside of my directive will not fire the fooControls clickTest. Why is clickTest not firing and logging to the console? is there a better way of doing this?

**Directive**

```
app.directive('fooList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: './app/views/fooList.html',
        scope: { obj: "=" },
        controller: 'fooController',
        controllerAs: 'b'
    };
});
```

**Controler**

```
app.controller('fooController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = [];

    $scope.ClickTest = function (num) {console.log(num);};
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="book in obj" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="pull-right"><button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="b.ClickTest(1)">ClickTest</button></h4>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

**EDIT**

The above html is a copy paste of foo-list. The full html is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<foo-list  obj="searchResults"></foo-list>
</body>
<html
```

Comment: In your example code the `<foo-list>` tag is not even used...

Comment: Also, why is it `b.ClickTest(1)`. You have ClickTest applied to your scope, it should just be `ClickTest(1)`

Comment: thank you @mcpDesigns it was the alias that was messing it up. I have this working in another project and the alias was just fine. Anyway removing the alias cleared up the issue. Thank you

Comment: If you make that the answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: Whoops, stolen... :P

Comment: @mcpDesigns i can unmark the answer. You got it first fair and square

Comment: No worries! Glad to of helped either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html should be changed to have the `ClickTest` function applied directly to the scope, not a variable in the scope. You also need to include a `<foo-list />` tag for your directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="book in obj" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Change b.ClickTest(1) to ClickTest(1)-->
        <h4 class="pull-right"><button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="ClickTest(1)">ClickTest</button></h4>
    </div>
    <br />
    <!-- Insert a foo-list tag -->
    <foo-list  obj="searchResults"></foo-list>
</div>
```